# FileStream openAsync throws Error #1009

Tags: air, actionscript-3

hi I have a problem regarding FileStream  openAsync read file, I have a listener and waiting on complete

```
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fName+'.'+EXT);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  


     if (!file.exists) {
              this.dispatchEvent(new AppEvent(AppEvent.DATA, null, false));                                         

     }else {

         fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileReadCompleteHandler);
         fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.READ);
         fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosedHandler);
         fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorHandler);
     }


     private function fileReadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
        var ob:Object;
        var fileStream:FileStream = FileStream(event.currentTarget);

        try {
            ob.source = fileStream.readObject();
        }catch (e:Error) {
            trace('error:' + e.message) 
        }

        fileStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileReadCompleteHandler);
        fileStream.close(); 

      }
```

on fileReadCompleteHandler I get error: **"Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."**
what I am missing, how can I read object from openAsync?

thanks

Comment: Can you share the stack trace for the error? Without the line number, it's difficult to know where the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize object ob, of course accessing fields of a null object gives you #1009:

```
    var ob:Object;
    var fileStream:FileStream = FileStream(event.currentTarget);

    try {
        ob.source = fileStream.readObject();
```

You need to:

```
    var ob:Object = new Object;
    var fileStream:FileStream = FileStream(event.currentTarget);

    try {
        ob.source = fileStream.readObject();
```

Comment: you are right Organis, this was my mistake, now it works as expected